# Laravel replace property with another if it is 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two columns, price and offer_price.

When I call $products->price, I would like it to bring back the offer_price if it is above 0, if not, return the price.

My modal:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products';
    public function type() {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductTypes', 'id', 'type_id');
    }

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductBrands', 'id', 'brand_id');
    }

    public function image() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductImages');
    }

    public function toArray() {

        $ar = $this->attributes;

        $ar['type'] = $this->type;
        $ar['brand'] = $this->spec_brand;
        $ar['price'] = $this->price;
        return $ar;
    }

    public function getSpecBrandAttribute() {
        $brand = $this->brand()->first();
        return (isset($brand->brand) ? $brand->brand : '');
    }

    public function getPriceAttribute() {
        $price = $this->price;
        return (isset($price->price) ? $price->price : '');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it here:

```
    $brands = array();
    $prices = array();
    $out = '';
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $brands[$product->brand->id] = $product->brand->brand;
        $prices[] = $product->price;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You can find your data in the `$attributes` array member of your model, rather than distinct member variables in your model.

How about:

```
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    $which = (0 < $this->attributes['offer_price'] ? 'offer_price' : 'price');
    return $this->attributes[$which];
}
```

Though I would recommend a name other than 'price', unless you completely want to mask 'price' from the usual Laravel interaction.  Perhaps `$modal->best_price`?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean? price will always be overridden by offer_price for a given product if offer_price is > 0, otherwise it just shows the normal price.

Comment: I mean that `getPriceAttribute()` masks `price` whenever `0 < offer_price`, so you cannot use `->price` to access price in that scenario.  If that's important to you, a new synthetic attribute would be needed.